# gocql package golang two file version in same install

Tags: linux, go

getting this error when trying to run a go file (which should run)

```
clusterCfg.ConnectTimeout undefined (type *gocql.ClusterConfig has no field 
or method ConnectTimeout)
```

1. When I look at the documentation of go 1.7 I find that ClusterConfig does have a field ConnectTimeout. (go version = 1.7).
2. If I go to the github.com directory in my go path I find a directory gocql. In this directory I find a file cluster.go which contains a definition for a struct ClusterConfig which does not have ConnectTimeout only a field Timeout.

---

```
go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/developer/gocode"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-
map=/tmp/go-build098468995=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

---

```
    {
        "Dir": "/home/developer/gocode/src/github.com/gocql/gocql",
        "ImportPath": "github.com/gocql/gocql",
        "Name": "gocql",
        "Doc": "Package gocql implements a fast and robust Cassandra driver 
         for the Go programming language.",
        "Target": 
        "/home/developer/gocode/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/gocql/gocql.a",
        "Root": "/home/developer/gocode",
        "GoFiles": [
            "address_translators.go",
            "cluster.go",
            "compressor.go",
            "conn.go",
            "connectionpool.go",
            "control.go",
            "debug_off.go",
            "doc.go",
            "errors.go",
            "events.go",
            "filters.go",
            "frame.go",
            "helpers.go",
            "host_source.go",
            "marshal.go",
            "metadata.go",
            "policies.go",
            "prepared_cache.go",
            "query_executor.go",
            "ring.go",
            "session.go",
            "token.go",
            "topology.go",
            "uuid.go"
        ],
        "IgnoredGoFiles": [
            "batch_test.go",
            "cass1batch_test.go",
            "cassandra_test.go",
            "compressor_test.go",
            "conn_test.go",
            "debug_on.go",
            "errors_test.go",
            "events_ccm_test.go",
            "fuzz.go",
            "marshal_test.go",
            "session_test.go",
            "stress_test.go",
            "topology_test.go",
            "tuple_test.go",
            "udt_test.go",
            "uuid_test.go",
            "wiki_test.go"
        ],
        "Imports": [
            "bufio",
            "bytes",
            "crypto/md5",
            "crypto/rand",
            "crypto/tls",
            "crypto/x509",
            "encoding/binary",
            "encoding/hex",
            "encoding/json",
            "errors",
            "fmt",
            "github.com/gocql/gocql/internal/lru",
            "github.com/gocql/gocql/internal/murmur",
            "github.com/gocql/gocql/internal/streams",
            "github.com/golang/snappy",
            "github.com/hailocab/go-hostpool",
            "golang.org/x/net/context",
            "gopkg.in/inf.v0",
            "io",
            "io/ioutil",
            "log",
            "math",
            "math/big",
            "math/rand",
            "net",
            "reflect",
            "regexp",
            "runtime",
            "sort",
            "strconv",
            "strings",
            "sync",
            "sync/atomic",
            "time",
            "unicode"
        ],
        "Deps": [
            "bufio",
            "bytes",
            "container/list",
            "context",
            "crypto",
            "crypto/aes",
            "crypto/cipher",
            "crypto/des",
            "crypto/dsa",
            "crypto/ecdsa",
            "crypto/elliptic",
            "crypto/hmac",
            "crypto/md5",
            "crypto/rand",
            "crypto/rc4",
            "crypto/rsa",
            "crypto/sha1",
            "crypto/sha256",
            "crypto/sha512",
            "crypto/subtle",
            "crypto/tls",
            "crypto/x509",
            "crypto/x509/pkix",
            "encoding",
            "encoding/asn1",
            "encoding/base64",
            "encoding/binary",
            "encoding/hex",
            "encoding/json",
            "encoding/pem",
            "errors",
            "fmt",
            "github.com/gocql/gocql/internal/lru",
            "github.com/gocql/gocql/internal/murmur",
            "github.com/gocql/gocql/internal/streams",
            "github.com/golang/snappy",
            "github.com/hailocab/go-hostpool",
            "golang.org/x/net/context",
            "gopkg.in/inf.v0",
            "hash",
            "hash/crc32",
            "internal/nettrace",
            "internal/race",
            "internal/singleflight",
            "internal/syscall/unix",
            "io",
            "io/ioutil",
            "log",
            "math",
            "math/big",
            "math/rand",
            "net",
            "os",
            "path/filepath",
            "reflect",
            "regexp",
            "regexp/syntax",
            "runtime",
            "runtime/cgo",
            "runtime/internal/atomic",
            "runtime/internal/sys",
            "sort",
            "strconv",
            "strings",
            "sync",
            "sync/atomic",
            "syscall",
            "time",
            "unicode",
            "unicode/utf16",
            "unicode/utf8",
            "unsafe"
        ],
        "TestGoFiles": [
            "address_translators_test.go",
            "cluster_test.go",
            "common_test.go",
            "control_test.go",
            "events_test.go",
            "filters_test.go",
            "frame_test.go",
            "framer_bench_test.go",
            "host_source_test.go",
            "metadata_test.go",
            "policies_test.go",
            "ring_test.go",
            "session_connect_test.go",
            "token_test.go"
        ],
        "TestImports": [
            "bytes",
            "compress/gzip",
            "flag",
            "fmt",
            "github.com/hailocab/go-hostpool",
            "golang.org/x/net/context",
            "io/ioutil",
            "log",
            "math/big",
            "net",
            "os",
            "sort",
            "strconv",
            "strings",
            "sync",
            "testing",
            "time"
        ]
    }
```

What have I done wrong? How can I have 2 versions of the same file? How do I fix it?

Comment: Any chance you have a `vendor` directory in your main app directory?

Comment: What do you mean "When I look at the documentation of go 1.7 I find that ClusterConfig does have a field ConnectTimeout."? gocql is not part of stdlib, so it shouldn't be in the documentation for any version of Go, and versions of the library are unrelated to versions of Go.

Comment: What does `go list -json github.com/gocql/gocql` show?

Comment: nothing called "vendor", above github.com is a Workspace directory containing multiple projects (apps). No colleages have seen this error.

Comment: Adrian, how do I find the version of the package?

Comment: edited to answer the question of captncraig

Comment: On invocation cqlsh shows:[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.3 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: Running grep -R vendor in one of the app spaces reports many instances of the word but no directory obvious

Comment: Appreciate the editing for what ever purpose that served, but would have preferred and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an answer, but is a solution. Rather than continue trying to salvage the vm I merely got another image and proceeded from there.